# Negative AIC or positive AIC?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, model-selection, aic

I have calculated AIC by using R-studio to compare models. However, I got the following both negative and positive AIC

AIC  8.52  0.41  -7.70  -5.84  -3.84  -2.10

Should I select the negative AIC or positive AIC?

Should I select the absolute value of AIC?

Should I select the lowest AIC although it is the negative value?

Which model should I choose?

I am a bit confuse because normally I get the positive value of AIC.

Thank you.

Comment: AIC can be both negative or positive, the smaller the value the "better" the model.

Comment: Thank you Tim
So, I should select AIC = -7.70. Is it correct?

Comment: AIC is just a criteria for model selection that if is smaller then suggests "better" model but you never use such values alone but consider also other arguments for or against a model.

Comment: Thank you for you explanation. However, I just want to check my understanding whether AIC = -7.70 is the best for the above case. Am I correct? Can someone answer me?

Comment: Yes, in this case it is the smallest value of those that you listed.